# Query runs fine in SQL Server but Errors in trying to read into a Pandas DF

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I have a query that I can run fine in SQL Server but errors trying to read it into a DF using PYOBC.

I've copy and pasted the exact query from SQL Server into a variable named query in my python script (works for all other queries).

When I run the query in SQL Server, this part:

```sql
;WITH DeDupe AS (
    -- Trace 105704 was received, returned to vendor, and re-received under same PO. DeDupe handles this
    SELECT DISTINCT A.PurchaseOrderID, A.POLineNumber, D.TraceID
    FROM #UniquePOs A
    LEFT JOIN Trace.ReceivingReport B WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON A.PurchaseOrderID = B.PurchaseOrderID AND A.POLineNumber = B.POLineNumber
    LEFT JOIN Trace.EventInstance C WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON B.EventInstanceID = C.InstanceID AND C.EventID = 'RCVD' -- Keep only receive events, not project transfers to avoid double-counting
    LEFT JOIN Trace.Trace D
    ON C.TraceID = D.TraceID
)
SELECT * INTO #DeDupe FROM DeDupe

SELECT * FROM #DeDupe; <---I take this part out when I try to run the query to get the second table.

;WITH TraceQtys AS (
    -- Use this to solve Case 3 below
    SELECT A.PurchaseOrderID, A.POLineNumber, SUM(B.Quantity) AS 'SumOfTraceQty'
    FROM #DeDupe A
    LEFT JOIN Trace.Trace B
    ON A.TraceID = B.TraceID
    GROUP BY A.PurchaseOrderID, A.POLineNumber
)
SELECT * INTO #TraceQtys FROM TraceQtys

SELECT * FROM #TraceQtys;
```

Returns these as results:

```
PurchaseOrderID                                    POLineNumber TraceID
-------------------------------------------------- ------------ -----------
007004                                             1            NULL
007004                                             1            41963

(2 rows affected)

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row affected)
PurchaseOrderID                                    POLineNumber SumOfTraceQty
-------------------------------------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------
007004                                             1            8.00000
```

Ran in my Python script:

```
query = 'SET NOCOUNT ON; ' + query
query = query.replace('GO', '')

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SL-SQL;'
                      'Database=TRACE DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
df.head()
```

The above returns the same result for the first table but an error for the second:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

This similar query works in Python:

```
query = '''
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH Temp as (
SELECT TraceID, ClassID, SUM(Quantity) as Q
FROM Trace.Trace
GROUP BY TraceID, ClassID
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM Temp
SELECT * FROM #Temp'''
```

It also runs if I take out this part in the Python query:

```
SUM(B.Quantity) AS 'SumOfTraceQty'
```

I have a similar piece of code that runs successfully (further up):

```sql
WITH POQtys AS (
    SELECT A.PurchaseOrderID, SUM(B.QtyVouched) AS POTotalQtyVouched
    FROM #orders A
    LEFT JOIN [MSS-ISD-DYN01].App.dbo.PurOrdDet B WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON A.PurchaseOrderID = B.PONbr AND B.InvtID IN ('DIR-MATERIALS', 'ASSET-INVENTORY')
    GROUP BY A.PurchaseOrderID
)
SELECT * INTO #POQtys FROM POQtys
```

Comment: TRY `SUM(ISNULL(B.Quantity,0))` to resolve your warning in second `CTE`.

Comment: @JIKEN, Thanks! This worked for me. I am guessing in Python you can't sum null values and in SQL Server you can?

Comment: @JIKEN, found calculations between NULL values is the root of my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107175/python-sql-pyodbc-allow-null-value-calculations

Comment: So, let me know this solution is resolved your root problem of `NULL` values or not, while doing any aggregation.

Comment: @JIKEN, thanks. Your solution helps me here. The deeper rooted problem is that pd.read_sql and read_sql_query reads in the NULLs as 0. I've looked around and it seems like there is no option to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

For Python cursor calls you can usually only submit one SQL statement at a time. Hence, why others worked but not your combined which maintains multiple SQL statements. However, you can use multiple CTEs in one call that even depend on each other and avoid the `SELECT...INTO` actions.

Below also uses more informative table aliases to kick the [A-B-C habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) and [No LOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) habit. Below can be read as one statement in Pandas' `read_sql`.

```sql
WITH DeDupe AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT u.PurchaseOrderID, u.POLineNumber, t.TraceID 
     FROM #UniquePOs u
     LEFT JOIN Trace.ReceivingReport r 
          ON u.PurchaseOrderID = r.PurchaseOrderID
          AND u.POLineNumber = r.POLineNumber 
     LEFT JOIN Trace.EventInstance e
          ON r.EventInstanceID = e.InstanceID 
          AND e.EventID = 'RCVD' 
     LEFT JOIN Trace.Trace t
          ON e.TraceID = t.TraceID 
), 
TraceQtys AS (
     SELECT d.PurchaseOrderID, d.POLineNumber, SUM(t.Quantity) AS 'SumOfTraceQty' 
     FROM DeDupe d
     LEFT JOIN Trace.Trace t
          ON d.TraceID = t.TraceID 
     GROUP BY d.PurchaseOrderID, t.POLineNumber
) 

SELECT * FROM TraceQtys
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Perhaps I should have been more clear. I toggle the ```SELECT * FROM #DeDupe;``` line in my code depending on whether I want to display the #DeDupe table or #TraceQtys in my Python script.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *toggle* and how that fits inside a Pandas data frame. Maybe run `read_sql` twice for *DeDupe* and *TraceQtys* data frames? Again, you cannot run multiple statements inside a cursor call.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am running read_sql twice. Once with each ```SELECT * FROM #____``` statement.

I've found that calculations with NULL values is the root of this whole problem. Created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107175/python-sql-pyodbc-allow-null-value-calculations