# pandas read_sql Imports NULLs as 0s

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

Edit:
Apparently my connection (PYODBC) is reading in the NULLs as 0s. I'd like to correct this on a "higher" level as I'll be reading in lots of SQL files. I can't find anything in the documentation to prevent this. Any suggestions?

I am importing a SQL file/query as a string and then using pd.read_sql to query my database. In SQL Server I can do calculations between NULL values which results in a NULL value, however, in Python, this errors out my script.

Query ran in SQL Server:

```
SELECT PurchaseOrderID, POTotalQtyVouched, NewColumn = PurchaseOrderID/POTotalQtyVouched FROM #POQtys;
```

Here is my desired output after running the query (which works in SQL Server):

```
PurchaseOrderID    POTotalQtyVouched   NewColumn
NULL               NULL                NULL
007004             8                   875.5
008017             21                  381.761904761905
008478             NULL                NULL
```

Running the query in Python:

```
query = '''
...
[Other code defining #POQTYs]
...
SELECT PurchaseOrderID, POTotalQtyVouched, NewColumn = PurchaseOrderID/POTotalQtyVouched FROM #POQtys;

'''
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=MSS-SL-SQL;'
                      'Database=TRACE DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Error in Python:

> DataError: ('22012', '[22012] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Divide by zero error encountered. (8134) (SQLFetch)')

Comment: It looks like your connection automatically converts `null` to `0` so just use a case expressions to prevent the calculation when the value is `null`.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, thanks for pointing me down the right path. This will work but since I will be doing this a lot for a lot of SQL files, I'd like to find another way of doing this.

Comment: Did you check that my suggestion is in fact actually the case? The more I think about it the more I think it can't be, because the computation happens within the SQL Server, unrelated to the connection. I actually think it must be different data being queried.

Comment: Yes, 
Query in Python:
`SELECT PurchaseOrderID, POTotalQtyVouched FROM #POQtys`

Returns the same table but with 0's instead of the NULLs

Comment: I think is a panda's problem. Check this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652457/adjust-pandas-read-sql-query-null-value-treatment) and [read_sql doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=read_sql#pandas.read_sql) especially the `coerce_float` param.

Comment: @Max, Thanks for the input. At first glance this would appear to be my solution, although the NULL values still come through as 0's.